# Coordinate Descent Method

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

> [image]

I am not very sure of how the value x2* = -3/10 was derived. I tried differentiating wrt f([-1/2, alpha]) but I could not get the answer. Any help is appreciated in letting me better understand coordinate descent.

Comment: Take the function
$$
f(x) = 5x^2 + 3x + \frac{5}{4}
$$
and differentiate it with respect to $x$. You should find that the minimum (where derivative is zero) is found at $x=-3/10$, unless you have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find $x_2$, we minimize the function
$$
g(\alpha) = f([-1/2,\alpha]) = 5\alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 5/4.
$$
To optimize this function on one variable, we can simply differentiate to find the critical point.
$$
g'(\alpha) = 10\alpha + 3 = 0 \implies \alpha = -\frac{3}{10} =  -0.3.
$$
Alternatively, you might remember from a precalculus class that the axis of a symmetry of the parabola $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ occurs at $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$.